# IE8 not displaying swf

Tags: internet-explorer-8, flash

If the browser does not detect the HTML5 Audio controller it will fallback a swf player.

But for some unknown reason IE8 does not display the swf player. 
The swfobject.js is in the same folder as the html.

**Here's the full code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
        </script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<center>
<audio controls preload="auto" autobuffer> 
    <source src="friday.ogg" />
    <source src="friday.mp3" />

        <div class="fallback">

            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="xspf_player.swf?playlist_url=playlist.xspf&autoplay=true
                &repeat_playlist=true&player_title=KICK&playlist_size=3"
                width="400" height="151">
                <param name="movie" value="xspf_player
                .swf? playlist_url=playlist.xspf&
                ;autoplay=true&repeat_playlist=true&player_title=
                KICK&playlist_size=3" />
            </object>

        </div>

</audio>

</center>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf")`, but there is no element with the id "myId" on your page.

Comment: Do I just remove this line? since I merely copy/pasted, to my knowledge is just junk code, right?

Comment: No, actually "myId" should represent the id of your object tag. You probably want to take a look at this section of the documentation : http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation#STEP_3:_Register_your_Flash_content_with_the_SWFObject_library_a